# Logi C270 webcam crash in Telegram Desktop

Tags: debian, webcam

System Spec:

- MX Linux on Pentium-Dual Core with 2GB of RAM.
- Webcam - Logi C270.
- Microphone - Logi C270 built in.

Problem:
After opening the Telegram Desktop, entering the settings and clicking on "Call Settings", Telegram crashes with the error below

```
# Fatal error in: ./src/api/video/i420_buffer.cc, line 53
# last system error: 1
# Check failed: height > 0 (-2147483648 vs. 0)
```

I tried to open Call Settings on other PC with AntiX Linux and with same webcam(c270), and there was no crash. I think, it's a problem with the driver.

Comment: The driver is the same, included in the kernel, and common to any Linux distro out there.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, ok, then, why this problem occur?

Comment: Check line 53 of the file mentioned in the error message to see what it says.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, i already checked this file. This is the procedure or function ```RTC_DCHECK_GT(height, 0);``` .